# Change Oracle XE port

Tags: oracle, port

This keeps bugging me:

Changing oracle port 8080 to another nnnn.

In the terminal I use

```
sudo nano /etc/default/oracle-xe
```

I then edit the

```
CONFIGURE_RUN=false
```

line and run the line in the term

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

The reason I want to do this is because if I install glassfish I don't want ports to conflict. Why does this not work? I am running 32 bit Ubuntu in workstation trial (I have not bought it yet). I want to create a development environment for EJB and get Java to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the XDB HTTP port for APEX, not the Oracle listener port. This short article [should do.](http://daust.blogspot.com/2006/01/xe-changing-default-http-port.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you i dont sleep sometimes very well an make silly mistakes! In the sql pane in the prowser [code]begin
dbms_xdb.sethttpport('nnnn');
end;[/code]

Works a treat! How do i get oracle to run sql in the terminal? Do i need to install something else because i have only used this in a windows environment.

Comment: Welcome to SO (StackOverflow). Please don't post additional questions as an answer. Ask a separate question on SO instead.